# Is a hole on earth pin normal?

Tags: grounding, plug

So there is this weird hole on top of the earth pin of an appliance:

[image]

I dont know whether this is normal or not, or whether it's safe to use or not. Should I repair it, or use it hoping that nothing would go wrong?

Comment: Normal - no. Safe - probably.  Repair - the only viable way is to replace the plug.

Comment: Contact is normally made along the sides rather than at the tip of the pin so it shouldn't be an issue. But ensure the tip isn't deformed enough to damage sockets as it's inserted and removed.

Comment: Empty inside pin less reliable then solid, could be broken if you put in and out often.